плаття чи сукня?
Чи коректно вживати обидва слова? Чи є якась різниця між ними?

«Словник української мови» у 20 томах:

Пла́ття, [родовий відмінок — платт]я, с[ередній рід].

Жіночий одяг, верхня частина якого, що відповідає кофті, становить єдине ціле з нижньою частиною, що відповідає спідниці; сукня. […]

збірн[е], заст[аріле]. Одяг. […]

збірн[е], заст[аріле]. Білизна. […]



Отже цей словник слово плаття у значенні «сукня» вважає цілком нейтральним (не розмовним/поетичним/тощо, не застарілим, не стилістично забарвленим). Хоча на практиці його все-таки вживають рідше (графік з 18-й версії «Генерального регіонально анотованого корпусу української мови»; суму вжитків плаття і сукня приведено до 100%):




Не знайду літературних підтверджень, та плаття - це наче одяг, як чоловічий, так і жіночий. Тим часом, сукня - це жіноче вбрання в прямому розумінні. Хоча сьогодні зустріти і чоловіка в сукні не диво.

@RomanMikhol, наскільки я розумію, у слова плаття є два значення — історичне значення «одяг» (як чоловічий, так і жіночий) і сучасне значення «сукня» (специфічний різновид жіночого вбрання).
